# SQL conditions with COUNT in select query

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following SQL query, I want to display if factor count is greater than one select NULL else return factor.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(factor) > 1 
            THEN NULL
        ELSE factor
    END
FROM
    TABLE 
WHERE 
    ColumnA = '1'
    AND ColumnB = '2';
```

However, I get this error:

[image]

EDITED

It is working fine if we use it as follows, however, I need to use factor in else part and Null in IF part

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN COUNT(factor) > 1 
           THEN 'A'
           ELSE 'B'
    END
FROM 
    TABLE 
WHERE 
    ColumnA = '1'
    AND ColumnB = '2';
```

Comment: This is clearly Oracle and not SQL Server.  They are completely different products.  Please use care in tagging questions as the solutions are usually different between different platforms.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko it is works fine if I use '1' like string in else part

Comment: what is the datatype of columnA,columnB and factor

Comment: your query makes no sense if count is 0 you have no factors anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use COUNT(factor) and factor in one expression, try an aggregation, mox(factor) or min(factor) should be the same...

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN COUNT(factor) > 1 
   THEN 
      NULL
   ELSE 
      MAX(factor)
   END
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ColumnA = '1'
AND ColumnB = '2';
```

But the error message doesn't fit, it should be

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60a3c0861e3cd747743d7ac9ecbee40a)

Comment: @nbk you got a syntax error, its TABLE1, not TABLE

Comment: @nbk, sorry, you took it to verbose,Ii just edited the query from op, which has only a _smbolic_ table name, that's the problem

Comment: yes, ok but the query make still no sense, ckecking existing factor and the repeat r NULL or getting the may of cator for the **whole** table of none exists

Comment: Objecttion, it is one way of getting either the one and only used value or null if no or distinct values are used...

Comment: it is completely unclear what factor he searches for